# Cannot start a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile, which attempts to setup Nginx with Phusion Passenger, and then install Ruby.

```
# Build command: docker build --force-rm --tag="rails" .
# Run command: docker run -P -d rails
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install nginx and passenger
RUN sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
RUN sudo sudo apt-get install -yf apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN sudo echo 'deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
RUN sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
RUN sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -yf nginx-extras passenger
RUN sudo service nginx restart

# Install rbenv and ruby
RUN sudo apt-get install -yf git autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev curl
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh
ENV PATH /root/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN rbenv install 2.1.5
RUN rbenv global 2.1.5

EXPOSE 80
```

Basically, I can build the image just fine, but I cannot start a container from this image.

This is my first time using docker, so I suspect that I need to use the CMD directive, but I have no idea what command should go there.

I appreciate any help to point out what is wrong with my Dockerfile.

Comment: What does *I cannot start a container from this image* mean? Do you get an error message? If so, which one? How do you try to start the container? …?

Comment: I don't get any error message. I start the container by docker run -P -d image_id. The status of the container right after started was Exited (0) some-time ago.

Comment: Yeah, you don't get an error message because everything worked :) I've added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The container is running successfully, its just exiting immediately as you don't specify any process to run. A container will only run as long as its main process. As you've run it in the background (the `-d` flag) it won't provide any output, which is a bit confusing.

For example:

```
$ docker run ubuntu echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

The container ran the command and exited as expected.

```
$ docker run -d ubuntu echo "Hello World"
efd8f9980c1c9489f72a576575cf57ec3c2961e312b981ad13a2118914732036
```

The same thing as happened, but as we ran with `-d`, we got the id of the container back rather than the output. We can get the output using the `logs` command:

```
$ docker logs efd8f9980c1c9489f72a576575cf57ec3c2961e312b981ad13a2118914732036
Hello World
```

What you need to do is start your rails app, or whatever process you want the container to run when you launch the container. You can either do this from the `docker run` command or using `CMD` statement in the Dockerfile. Note that the main process must stay in the foreground - if it forks to the background the container will exit.

If you want to get a shell in a container, start it with `-it` e.g:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

To be honest, I think you'd be better served by using an official image e.g. https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rails/.

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere thanks to your answer. Indeed I have to run something otherwise the docker process will exit. I found that the command `nginx` can start nginx, as shown from the official Nginx dockerfile. However, even if I run that command, the container exits immediately. How can I keep nginx running?

Comment: I also tried the passenger docker prior to doing this, but they don't have the latest Ruby. I can start from their image and upgrade Ruby, but I also want to learn how to build my own image from scratch.

Comment: You need to start nginx in the foreground. Looking at the nginx dockerfile, you need `nginx -g daemon off`

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this works!! To correct your command, it should be `nginx -g "daemon off;"`. Perhaps you should update your answer for other viewers that the process to run has to be in foreground. Also, I can include this in Dockerfile `RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Actually, I already mention that in the answer :)
You can also put it directly in the Dockerfile: `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`
Anyway, I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ENTRYPOINT` to start what you want, check the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/).

Comment: Hmm, I think the Ubuntu image runs /bin/bash by default.

Comment: I don't think so as when using a Dockerfile you're just building an image. But you can ssh to it.

Comment: I'm saying this Dockerfile inherits from the Ubuntu image which has a CMD line launching /bin/bash. This will get run when you launch a container if you don't override it.

Comment: Ubuntu image indeed runs /bin/bash by default. Here is the status of a container, showing that it ran /bin/bash: 40e9817b2a21        khang/rails:latest   "/bin/bash"         11 seconds ago      Exited (0) 10 seconds ago                          jolly_archimedes

Answer (score 0):

See what the logs says by issuing

`docker logs rails`

or, as

`docker ps -an 1`

should show the last id, with the command

`docker logs this_id`